# YouTube iFrame : trigger click on share button

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I have an iFrame YouTube player on my web page. I need to create a button on my page which opens the sharing YouTube Overlay, like the top right button in the YouTube player :

[image]

I can't find how to do this using the YouTube API, something like

```
player.openSharingOverlay()
```

I tried to trigger a click event on the iFrame button on the onReady event but the same origin policy doesn't allow this.

Is there a way to achieve this ? I realize it is not a very useful feature, the native button does the job, but marketing guys don't think that way...

Comment: Some aspects of the player are not controllable via the API.  I'm willing to bet that this is one of them.  I suggest just using the link that youtube provides when you do click on the share button.  It's the URL for the video with `#action=share` added on at the end.

Comment: I also think it is not controllable, I saw nothing in the docs about that. I wonder if there is a clean workaround. Thanks for the answer but I need to open the sharing overlay in the iFrame (and stay on my page). I'm afraid it's not possible...I need to talk to the marketing guys :)...